# Undeploying Business Network

Tags: hyperledger-composer

Using HyperLedger Composer 0.19.1, I can't find a way to undeploy my business network. I don't necessarily want to upgrade to a newer version each time, but rather replacing the one deployed with a fix in the JS code for instance. Any replacement for the undeploy command that existed before?

Answer (score 0):

There is no replacement for the old undeploy command, and in fact it it not really undeploy - merely hiding the old network.

Be aware that everytime you upgrade a network it creates a new Docker Image and Container so you may want to tidy these up periodically.  (You could also try to delete the BNA from the Peer servers but these are very small in comparison to the docker images.)

It might not help your situation, but if you are rapidly developing and iterating you could try this in the online Playground or local Playground with the Web profile - this is fast and does not create any new images/containers.

Comment: Can't really use the playground in my situation. Thanks anyway. Any documentation of all we have to do to get rid off a given deployed BNA? stopping the docker container, removing the image. What else? How can we remove the BNA from the peers?

Comment: These commands will list the installed versions of Business networks on a Peer, so you could delete from here.  I would sassume that you will have to delete from each peer.
 `docker exec -it peer0.org1.example.com /bin/sh`
 `ls /var/hyperledger/production/chaincodes/`
 `exit`